# Как отключить эту штуку при написании кода?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я хожу стрелочками влево, вправо по коду в visual studio, я не могу стать между символами, а только могу заменить символ, как это отключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажми кнопку Insert на клавиатуре.